# Java- Getting Json by parts

Tags: java, json, partial

Generally is there a way to get a big JSON string by a single request by parts?

For example, if I have a JSON string consisting of three big objects and having each size of 1mb, can I somehow in a single request get the first 1mb then parse it while other 3 objects are still being downloaded, instead of waiting for the full 3mb string to download?

Comment: Look into JSON streaming. The Jackson library has an [API](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes#Streaming_API_Example) for this. There's probably others out there as well.

Comment: You can parse the JSON string byte by byte, but you won't be able to extract anything from it until the parsing is complete.

Comment: If you want to get one object at a time you have to send 3 json strings and not one that combine the three others.

Comment: You can't do anything with it until the entire stream is retrieved anyway..

Answer (score 0):

If you know how big the parts are, it would be possible to split your request in three using HTTP1.1's range requests. Assuming your ranges are defined correctly, you should be able to get the JSON objects directly from the server (if the server supports range requests).

Note that this hinges on a) the server's capability to handle range requests, b) the idempotency of your REST operation (it could very well run the call three times, a cache or reverse proxy may help with this) and c) your ability to know the ranges before you call.